# Now that `invoke` is soft-deprecated, what's the alternative?

Tags: r, functional-programming, tidyverse

[`rlang::invoke()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/invoke.html) is now soft-deprecated,  [`purrr::invoke()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/invoke.html#see-also) retired. These days, what is the tidy approach to programmatically calling a function with a list of arguments?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you are trying to do? There might not be a complete replacement but there might be an alternative to do a particular thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tldr;** Use `exec` instead of `invoke`; use `map2` plus `exec` instead of `invoke_map`.

---

### Example for `invoke`

With retired `invoke`

```
set.seed(2020)
invoke(rnorm, list(mean = 1, sd = 2), n = 10)
#[1]  1.7539442  1.6030967 -1.1960463 -1.2608118 -4.5930686  2.4411470
#[7]  2.8782420  0.5412445  4.5182627  1.2347336
```

With `exec`

```
set.seed(2020)
exec(rnorm, n = 10, !!!list(mean = 1, sd = 2))
#[1]  1.7539442  1.6030967 -1.1960463 -1.2608118 -4.5930686  2.4411470
#[7]  2.8782420  0.5412445  4.5182627  1.2347336
```

---

### Example for `invoke_map`

Similarly, instead of `invoke_map` you'd use `map2` with `exec`. Previously, you'd use `invoke_map` to use a function with different sets of arguments

```
set.seed(2020)
invoke_map(rnorm, list(list(mean = 0, sd = 1), list(mean = 1, sd = 1)), n = 10)
#    [[1]]
#     [1]  0.3769721  0.3015484 -1.0980232 -1.1304059 -2.7965343  0.7205735
#     [7]  0.9391210 -0.2293777  1.7591313  0.1173668
#
#    [[2]]
#     [1]  0.1468772  1.9092592  2.1963730  0.6284161  0.8767398  2.8000431
#     [7]  2.7039959 -2.0387646 -1.2889749  1.0583035
```

Now, use `map2` with `exec`

```
set.seed(2020)
map2(
    list(rnorm),
    list(list(mean = 0, sd = 1), list(mean = 1, sd = 1)),
    function(fn, args) exec(fn, n = 10, !!!args))
#    [[1]]
#     [1]  0.3769721  0.3015484 -1.0980232 -1.1304059 -2.7965343  0.7205735
#     [7]  0.9391210 -0.2293777  1.7591313  0.1173668
#
#    [[2]]
#     [1]  0.1468772  1.9092592  2.1963730  0.6284161  0.8767398  2.8000431
#     [7]  2.7039959 -2.0387646 -1.2889749  1.0583035
```

Sadly, the `map2` plus `exec` syntax is not as concise as `invoke_map`, but it is perhaps more canonical.

A few comments that may help avoid issues when using `map2` plus `exec`:

1. The first argument of `map2` must be a `list`. So `map2(list(rnorm), ...)` will work. Just providing the function as `map2(rnorm, ...)` will not. This is different to `invoke_map`, which accepted both a `list` of functions and a function itself.
2. The second argument needs to be a `list` of argument `list`s. `map2` will iterate through the top-level `list`, and then use the big-bang operator `!!!` inside `exec` to force-splice the `list` of function arguments.

Comment: The comment at the bottom of this answer, #2, is very, very important.  I just wasted an hour troubleshooting before finding that the parameter essentially needs to be "list(list(param))".  This answer was super-helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's been about a year and no clear replacement was published. What I do in these scenarios is creating a lazy function call and evaluating it. Which is a nice decoupling `invoke` or `exec` do not have, since the call object can be passed around.

```
arglist <- list(n = 100, mean = 2, sd = 3)
aFunctionCall <- rlang::call2(rnorm, !!!arglist)

aFunctionCall
rlang::eval_bare(aFunctionCall)
```